# How to reference users across projects in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-boards

I have 2 private projects in my Azure DevOps Organization, say Project A and Project B. I need to mention a User in Project B from a work item in Project A. I'm able to do it. But the mentioned user is not able to view the Work Item as he don't have access. Any Solution or Work Around to achieve this?

Comment: Do you not want to give reader access to work items in Project A for the user?

Answer (score 0):

Giving Reader Access permissions will solve the problem of user being able to view the work item.

If you haven't already given reader access to the user, try giving it and see if that helps.

See the below Image for reference :

Click on Project Settings -> Permissions -> Readers -> Click on Add -> and add that user.

[image: reader access]

[image]

Comment: Hi Monica. Thank you for your reply. I know that this will work out. But this will allow the user to view every Work Item. I don't want that. I need him to view only the Work Item mentioned.

Comment: @Grenston - That is not possible, Either the user sees all work Items or nothing. There are no special permissions to allow certain work Items to appear or get blocked. 

Please feel free to "Accept as answer" if the above answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we cannot set permissions for a single work item. If you would like that feature, please use the below link and create a request for this feature: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21. This link is directly monitored by the product team and they will look into this request and share their views on the same. If lot of users request for the same feature, they will add this item to backlog to implement in the future sprints.